# passphrase in thunderbird with enigmail 1.6

Tags: thunderbird, passphrase, enigmail

I am using Ubuntu 13.10.

Two days ago I installed Enigmail 1.6 for Thunderbird. It works!
Unfortunately I have to type in my passphrase everytime I receive or send an encrypted mail.

Is there a way that thunderbird gets the passphrase automatically and I don't need to enter the passphrase again when I receive or send an encrypted mail?

Thank you!
New Ubuntu User

Answer (score 1):

1. Ensure that you switch on the remember this password checkbox in the
   password dialog.
2. After entering the password check the password below
   "Settings/Security/Password".
3. Check also `signon.rememberSignons` in `about:config` page (or in the file `prefs.js` in thunderfird config directory).

See also this pages for some more ideas: [Password not remembered - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_not_remembered_%28Thunderbird%29)

Comment: Hi Mtesh Shah,
thank you for your answer. Where exactly is this checkbox?
http://s7.directupload.net/images/131213/7cdzyvlx.png
http://s1.directupload.net/images/131213/t9h5ip5y.png

Comment: Sometime checkbox is disable to enable here is the steps: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Password_not_remembered_%28Thunderbird%29

Comment: Hi,
I do not have "user_pref("signon.rememberSignons", false);"
http://s14.directupload.net/images/131213/worxd4zj.png